# Compress a set of log files in a folder depending on number of files

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to know if there is any way to compress a set of .txt files in a folder using scripting when the number of files get more than a set limit. 
The txt files are automatically generated by another script.

Answer (score 4):

You can use array size to detect the number of files:

```
limit=100
files=(*.txt)
if (( ${#files[@]} > limit )) ; then
    zip archive.zip *.txt
fi
```

Comment: Hey, can you please tell me how the line `${#files[@]}` works. Thanks.

Comment: @Tarun: See `man bash`. It returns the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want [`logrotate`](https://fedorahosted.org/logrotate/) with a custom (non-`/etc`) configuration file with rules for compressing/removing by size.